Does it make sense to Full Back up weekly or Back up Transaction Log every 15 min?
I have to make a decision (at work) to choose which option is more feasible using SQL Server 2019:
Option 1: Full backups sent once per week and differential backups sent between weekly backups.
Option 2: Full backup sent once. Transaction log backups sent every 15 minutes. Additional full backups and differential backs sent as needed upon request.
I am leaning toward Option 1 because managing Transaction Logs that are went every 15 minutes seem to be a lot to manage.
Which method would make more sense?
It is a small data coming from a third vendor that we are storing in SQL Server 2019 in VM. After data is ingested, there is not going to be anything like distributing to other party from our SSMS.  I am not sure about "Point in Time Recovery" nor RPO or RTO. I have not gotten into Full or Simply Recovery Mode part yet.


Which option makes more sense / easier?

First question is what problem you are going to solve?
How are you going to use your backup?
Are you setting log shipping to other party?
Do you need point in time recovery?
Does your database in full or simply recovery mode?
What are your RPO or RTO targets?

managing Transaction Logs that are went every 15 minutes seem to be a lot to manage.

Not at all. sp_DatabaseRestore will do the magic. Just run it on the regular basis and it will pickup new logs to apply.
EDIT.

it is a small data coming from a third vendor that we are storing in SQL Server 2019 in VM

Sounds like you are configuring log shipping.
Anyways, setup a job to run sp_DatabaseRestore on the regular basis. The job should not run every 15 minutes to apply the latest log. It could run once an hour to apply several logs or even daily to apply all logs for the day.
There are good examples for parameters.
Here is my parameters. We are restoring the logs and open the database in read-only mode.
exec [sp_DatabaseRestore] @Database='mydatabase',
    @BackupPathFull='E:\Backups\myserver\mydatabase\FULL\',
    @BackupPathLog ='E:\Backups\myserver\mydatabase\LOG\',
    @MoveFiles = 1, 
    @MoveDataDrive ='D:\MSSQL\STBY_DATA\',
    @MoveLogDrive ='E:\MSSQL\STBY_LOG\',
    @RunRecovery = 0,
    @ContinueLogs = 1,
    @StandbyMode  = 1,
    @StandbyUndoPath  = 'E:\MSSQL\STBY_LOG\',
    @Execute='Y'


I am not sure when you mentioned "The job should not run every 15 minutes to apply the latest log. It could run once an hour to apply several logs or even daily to apply all logs for the day".  If Transaction log backups sent every 15 minutes, that means there will be around 96 files per day, right? I have other nightly process that I developed which grabs all files from previous day, and process all together. But, I am talking about 24 hours (all each hour). I am trying to get a better direction, which option (1) or (2) makes sense.  What is your take?

My point is - if you are not manually build 'restore log ' commands it doesn't matter how many files to process 24, 96 or more. sp_DatabaseRestore will read each file, look at LSN and build restore plan. If you populate @BackupPathDiff parameter it can take advantage of diff backups to skip log files.

Is using "BackupPathDiff" parameter more like using Option 1), then? Sorry I am new to the game.

You can use both. Applying diff backups is like shortcut to reach specific LSN and skip applying logs

So you are saying, one Full Back up and apply "BackupPathDiff" (diff backups)? No weekly Full Back up, correct?

You could use this approach. However diff backups are cumulative so you have to overwrite your database with weekly fulls. Next if someone run full backup without COPY_ONLY your diff will fail to restore. So log backups is way more reliable as log backups are incremental.

Sorry I am confused. So, your approach is more like Option 1 or Option 2?

Option 2 with ability to apply diff backups in case of failures, missing log backups etc. implemented via sp_DatabaseRestore

Yes.
Refer to How to Configure Ola Hallengren’s Database Maintenance Scripts for Backups
To summarize:

Run Maintenance Solution.sql
Configure the Agent Job(s) with the correct database name(s) & backup path(s) for your instance
Add a weekly schedule for the full backup & enable the job
Manually run the jobs and test a restore using the media it generates


First thing you need to consider is your tolerance to data loss in case of a disaster.
RTOs/RPOs define your backup strategy and not the overhead of management. For example : If you have a server crash or a data issue how much of data loss can you tolerate?
If you say we cannot have data loss of 15 minutes (ideally) then you need regular log backups running every 15 minutes.
Now full and Differential backups will depend on how big your database is. If the full backup takes 2 minutes then I would just have a full backup over night followed by regular log backups running every 15 minutes.
In case of a disaster you will restore the full backup and the all the log backups available.
Once you have figured out your strategy, then youu need to choose the way you would like the backup taken.

Avoid keeping backups on the same server,ideally move it to cloud storage (s3 or azure storage account)

Ola Hallengren's solution or simple SQL Server maintenance plans should be good enough.



If you take log backups every 15 minutes, and one fails, won't you lose more data than your RPO defines?

Yes you will not meet RPO if a backup fails and disaster  strikes. Which is why backup monitoring /alerting also needs to be part of the overall planning. Ideally 15 minute log backup should do it but a  failure can happen even to the last full backup

Why not take log backups every 5 minutes so that losing one isn't catastrophic to RPO goals?

@Erk Darling Thank you all for chiming in.  Knowing that it will be set up in Azure VM (SQL 2019), I am not worrying to much about losing data. I think with Azure, there is a back up capability. I am just trying to get a better idea which one could be more less maintainable/less headache to maintain on a daily basis. First, we have small data to maintain. If we automate the Full Backup once per week and set up differential on a daily basis, wouldn't it be easier? I am just worrying about Transaction logs sending out every 15 min that is 96 files a day that I have to keep track, no?

@ErikDarling : Yes can be 5 minutes ,no problem with that. Just need to make sure we monitor it to not overlap in case the backup time increases.

@Java : You can use Azure backups which works well and will give you a good control via backup policy. If you are choosing such solution then you shouldn't worry about the number of files as they are managed by the solution itself.

@RamakantDadhichi Speaking of Azure backups, is this (Option 2 (I guess) - the original question) process something that can be done in Azure SQL, not dealing with/bypassing IaaS (using SQL 2019 in VM)?
